# jQuery change input value via jquery not work after user manual edit

Tags: jquery, input, attr

I'm experiencing this trouble with jQuery and attr() function.

Take a look:

```
one <input id='one' type="text"><br>
two <input id='two' type="text">

<script>
$('#one').on('input',
             function(){
                 var result = 'test'
                 $('#two').attr('value',result);
             }
            );
</script>
```

This is the trouble:

1. I type something in the 'one' input;
2. the 'test' text was correctly inserted in the 'two' input.
3. Now I edit the content of the 'two' input.
4. Now if I type something new in the 'one' input , the 'two' input content isn't replaced with the 'test' text ! Why ?! How can I fix it ?

P.S.
See the live code here http://jsfiddle.net/5XQJj/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.val()` to set input values:

http://jsfiddle.net/dh23j/

```
$('#two').val(result);
```

Often, setting element attributes won't update more than once. You need to update their properties instead using `.prop` or using functions intended for the purpose, like `.val()`.

Comment: great ! but If I need to update the value property also, sould I do something like `$('#two').val(result).attr('value',result)` ??

Comment: No, `.val()` should do that for you. I believe that's probably what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: in firebug i cannot see this.. are you sure ?

Comment: Fairly. What are you looking at? Do you need to refresh a watch maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#one').on('input', function () {
    var result = 'test'
    $('#two').prop('value', result);
});
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5nsRu/)</kbd>

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

---

Better use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5nsRu/1)</kbd>

```
$('#two').val(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.val()` rather than `.attr` or `.prop`

updated JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5XQJj/6/

```
$('#one').on('change', function () {
    var result = 'test'
    $('#two').val(result);
});
```